# How to access a particular element in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

i'm making an shopping website. I have a list of products with unique ID, different specifications, and quantity. I have a **JSON** which looks something like this:

```
{    
            "ProductId" : "1",
            "ProductCode" : "",
            "ProductName" : "XYZ",
            "Specifications" : {
                "Size" : ["S","M","L","XL","XXL"],
                "GrossWeight" : "200gm each",
                "Colour" : ["Beige"]
            },
            "SellingPrice" : 80,
            "MinimumOrderQuantity" : "1",
            "MaximumOrderQuantity" : "1",
            "ShippingCharges" : "75",
            }
```

There are some products with **Quantity** not more than 1. If the user adds a product which has only 1 Quantity in my table, I want to stop the user from adding the same product again if it already exists in cart. I'm using `localStorage` to save the product on button click.

This is my code:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("productTable") != null)
   {
      productTable = JSON.parse(localStorage["productTable"]);
      for(var x in productTable) {
          serialNumber++; 
   }
    productTable[serialNumber]={
            serialNumber: serialNumber, 
            ProductId : Id, 
            Colour : selectedColour, 
            Size : selectedSize, 
            QuantityAdded : selectedQuantity
          };
      }
     else {
            productTable[serialNumber]={
            serialNumber: serialNumber, 
            ProductId : Id, 
            Colour : selectedColour, 
            Size : selectedSize, 
            QuantityAdded : selectedQuantity
          };
      }
```

**UPDATE:** I'm using `LocalStorage` which looks like this when I add an item:

```
{serialNumber: 1, ProductId: "5", Colour: "Grey", Size: "N/A", QuantityAdded: "1"}
```

I am able to add the product in cart. How can i stop the user from adding the same product again?

Answer (score 0):

```
let product = {product_id: 1, ....}
// make an entry in local storage using product id which will be unique
// so in any case if local storage has product id as key available, do 
// not add 
if (product.quantity > 1 || !localStorage.getItem(product.product_id)) 
{
    localStorage.setItem[product.product_id] = product;
}else {
    // update login
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54807978/edit) your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
   if (localStorage.getItem("productTable") != null) {
      productTable = JSON.parse(localStorage["productTable"]);
      for (var x in productTable) {
          serialNumber++; 
      }
      if (selectedQuantity >= 1 && productTable[serialNumber].MaximumOrderQuantity == 1) {
        alert("Please don't add more than one of these items");
        return;
      }
    }

    productTable[serialNumber] = {
      serialNumber: serialNumber, 
      ProductId: Id, 
      Colour: selectedColour, 
      Size: selectedSize, 
      QuantityAdded: selectedQuantity
    };
```

Comment: Hi @MarcoS, thankyou for your reply. I tried this code but it gave me an error: MaximumOrderQuantity not defined.

Comment: This means your JSON data does not comply with the format you did specify in your question...

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are setting the products in your map based on the increasing value of `serial number`, as you use serial number which can be different for the same products as the key you just have one option to identify if the product is already added to your map and that is to loop through all the values in `productTable` and check for the product id and check before adding it to the table.
`assuming productTable is a map`:

```html
productTable.forEach((productItem: Product, key: any) => {
    if(productItem.Id === Id){
    //this product is already there check for maximum quantity
    if(productItem.MaximumQuantity <= 1){
    //there is just 1 possible item so don't add it
    }else{
      // there is still space to add then proceed with adding the product
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Thriller, thankyou for your reply. I tried your code and I got an error that this approach is for .ts  not .js. Can you please write this in .js.

Comment: I believe the way to do it in JS is with `for (var key in productTable) {
   var productItem = productTable[key];
    if(productItem.Id === Id){
    //this product is already there check for maximum quantity
    if(productItem.MaximumQuantity <= 1){
    //there is just 1 possible item so don't add it
    }else{
      // there is still space to add then proceed with adding the product
    }
}`

Comment: hi @Thriller, can you please see my code on https://github.com/pradhanadi/Webiste and tell me where i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that `serialNumber` is the product count of a specific `Id`

```js
const data = [{
  "ProductId": "1",
  "ProductCode": "",
  "ProductName": "XYZ",
  "Specifications": {
    "Size": ["S", "M", "L", "XL", "XXL"],
    "GrossWeight": "200gm each",
    "Colour": ["Beige"]
  },
  "SellingPrice": 80,
  "MinimumOrderQuantity": "1",
  "MaximumOrderQuantity": "1",
  "ShippingCharges": "75",
}];
const newProduct = {"ProductId": 1, MaximumOrderQuantity: 1};

const products = data.filter(({ProductId})=>ProductId===newProduct.ProductId);

if(newProduct.MaximumOrderQuantity >= products.length){
  //can't add product because already a maximum amount exists
  console.log("Maximum quantity already attained");
} else {
  data.push(newProduct);
}

const res = JSON.stringify(data);

console.log(res);
```